# Generate the Rummy Sequence

Tags: code-golf, math, array

Your task is to take an input `n` and output element `n` of the Rummy Sequence, a sequence which I made (looking on OEIS will not help you).

## Definition

Each element of the Rummy Sequence is a set of truthy or falsey values. Ex.: `[true, false]`.

The steps to producing a member of the Rummy Sequence are quite simple:

1. Start out with the first index, `[]` (this is element 0).
2. Set the leftmost falsey to truthy. If there are no falseys to change, then increase the length of the list by 1 and set all members of the new list to falsey.
3. Repeat step 2 until reaching element `n`.

## Example

Let's define our function as `rummy(int n)` (stuff in `{}` is a step taken to get to the answer):

```
>>> rummy(5)
{[]}
{[false]}
{[true]}
{[false, false]}
{[true, false]}
[true, true]
```

## Rules

- Standard loopholes apply.
- Must work for inputs 0 through your language's upper numerical bound.
- You may output in any way you see fit, provided that it is clear that the output is a set of truthy/falseys.

## Trivia

I call this the "Rummy Sequence" because, starting at index 2, it defines the sets you would need to lay down in each round of [Progressive Rummy](http://www.rummy-games.com/rules/progressive-rummy.html), where falsey is a book and truthy is a run.

## Test Cases

```
>>> rummy(0)
[]

>>> rummy(1)
[false]

>>> rummy(6)
[false, false, false]

>>> rummy(20)
[true, true, true, true, true]

>>> rummy(1000)
[true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
```

Comment: This is kinda like counting binary in reverse

Comment: @ThreeFx Except that, when adding `1` to `11`, you get `000` instead of `100`. ;P

Comment: Can our answer be one-indexed?

Comment: I think you should include a few more test cases, even if the outputs are implicitly mentioned in the example. My first revision broke with the corner case 1...

Comment: @VTCAKAVSMoACE That would make it bijective binary (which we also have a challenge for), but there are more differences in that every number is always of the form `1*0*`.

Comment: @Downgoat You may, but you should note that in your answer.

Comment: @Dennis Sure thing. :D

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>94</s> <s>92</s> <s>72</s> <s>70</s> <s>66</s> 64 bytes

*Saved 6 bytes thanks to Neil!*

```
n=>[...Array(a=Math.sqrt(8*n+1)-1>>1)].map((_,l)=>l<n-a*(a+1)/2)
```

I don't think this can be golfed more. At least with the equations.

### Explanation

They are two main equations (`n` is input):

```
(Math.sqrt(8*n+1)-1)/2
```

This will give the total size the output array will need to be. In my program I used `>>1` instead of `(...)/2` these are the same as the first bit in binary has a value of 2. Shifting it will result in in `floor(.../2)`

---

```
n-a*(a+1)/2
```

This is the amount of `true`s there will be. `a` is the result of the previous expression.

---

This is what the syntax does:

```
[...Array(n)]
```

This code generates an array with range `[0, n)` in this answer `n` is the first equation.

---

`.map((_,l)=>l<n)` this will loop through the above range, `l` is the variable containing the current item in the range. If the item is less than the amount of trues they are (determined by second equation), then it will return `true`, else `false`.

Comment: Use `>>1` instead of `/2|0`. Use `(_,l)=>` instead of `.keys()`.

Comment: @Neil thanks! That saved a quite a bit. By your last point, do you mean to use `Array.from()`?, fill, or something else?

Comment: No, I was thinking of `[...Array(a)].map((_,l)=>)` which I believe is slightly shorter, but good catch on removing some of the `()`s when switching to `>>1`, I hadn't spotted that!

Comment: Oh, there's also `a*-~a/2`; I don't know why I didn't think of it before.

Answer (score 6):

### Python, 51 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i=0:n>i and f(n+~i,i+1)or[1]*n+[0]*(i-n)
```

Outputs a list of 1's and 0's.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>13</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ḷṗ2SÞ⁸ị1,0x
```

The code does not work in the latest version of Jelly before the challenge was posted, but it did work in [this version](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/tree/f37cfb4fd4b16dae5dd0eda54749af40f2446353), which predates the challenge.

Indices are 1-based. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bi24bmXMlPDnuKBuOG7izEsMHg&input=&args=MTAwMQ) (takes a few seconds) or [verify multiple inputs at once](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bi24bmXMlPDnuKBuOG7izEsMHgKUsOH4oKsRw&input=&args=MjE).

#### How it works

```
Ḷṗ2SÞ⁸ị1,0x  Main link. Argument: n (integer)

Ḷ            Unlength; yield [0, ..., n - 1].
 ṗ2          Take the second Cartesian power, i.e., generate the array of all
             pairs of elements of [0, ..., n - 1].
   SÞ        Sort the pairs by their sum. The sort is stable, so ties are broken
             by lexicographical order.
     ⁸ị      Retrieve the pair at index n.
       1,0x  Map [a, b] to a copies of 1 and b copies of 0.
```

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 8 bytes

```
_@{y/RQy
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=_%40%7By%2FRQy&input=7&test_suite=0&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7&debug=0) or [Test Suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=_%40%7By%2FRQy&input=7&test_suite=0&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7&debug=0)

This is exponentially slow.

#### Explanation:

```
_@{y/RQyQQ    implicit Qs at the end, (Q = input)
       yQ     2*Q
    /RQ       divide each number in [0, 1, ..., 2*Q-1] by Q
              this results in a list of Q zeros and Q ones
   y          take all subsets
  {           remove duplicates
 @       Q    take the Qth element
_             print it reversed
```

Answer (score 4):

### 05AB1E, 27 bytes

```
8*>t<;ïÐ>*;¹s-ïD1s×Š-0s×JSï
```

Will see if I can golf it some more and add an explanation in the morning.

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=OCo-dDw7w6_DkD4qO8K5cy3Dr0Qxc8OXxaAtMHPDl0pTw68&input=MTAwMA)

Answer (score 4):

## Java, <s>117</s> 110 bytes

```
enum B{T,F};B[]r(int n){int i=0,c=0,j=0;while(n>=i)i+=++c;B[]a=new B[c-1];for(;j<n-i+c;)a[j++]=B.T;return a;}
```

created my own boolean type, which allowed me to save 7bytes

Comment: That use of the enum is clever. +1

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>69</s> 63 bytes

```python
a=b=0
exec'a,b=[a-1,b+1,0][a<1:][:2];'*input()
print[1]*b+[0]*a
```

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/hXp8Jt).

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2, 61 bytes

```python
j=(2*input()+.25)**.5-.5
print[i/j<j%1for i in range(int(j))]
```

Solves for *n = j·(j+1)/2*. Input is taken from stdin.

**Sample Usage**

```python
$ echo 20 | python rummy-seq.py
[True, True, True, True, True]

$ echo 50 | python rummy-seq.py
[True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False]
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/8nMLWo).

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 21 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
{⍵⌷↑,/(↓0 1↓⍳≥\⍳)¨⍳⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/v/pR79ZHPdsftU3U0dd41DbZQMEQSD7q3fyoc2kMkNI8tALE6d1a@z/tUduER719j/qmevo/6mo@tN4YqAvICw5yBpIhHp7B/zWAag0NNHVAEr1TH3XMSANrNzQAAA)